# Drupal 7 exception 'EntityMalformedException' trying to run search index cron

Tags: php, drupal, cron

I have a Drupal 7 site and I'm struggling to find a solution to the following problem.

I have all my cron tasks are running fine but the search indexing cron. It produces this error in the logs and stops from indexing. It looks like it has something to do with the `entity_extract_ids()` function in field.multilingual.inc, but I have no clue where to start on this. Here is the error log:

```
exception 'EntityMalformedException' with message 'Missing bundle property on entity of type node.' in /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/common.inc:7562 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/field/field.multilingual.inc(268): entity_extract_ids('node', Object(stdClass)) 
#1 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/field/field.attach.inc(1111): field_language('node', Object(stdClass), NULL, 'en')
#2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/node/node.module(1358): field_attach_prepare_view('node', Array, 'search_index', 'en') 
#3 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/node/node.module(1284): node_build_content(false, 'search_index', 'en') 
#4 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/node/node.module(2668): node_view(false, 'search_index') 
#5 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/node/node.module(2650): _node_index_node(Object(stdClass)) 
#6 [internal function]: node_update_index() 
#7 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/module.inc(826): call_user_func_array('node_update_ind...', Array) 
#8 /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/search/search.module(363): module_invoke('node', 'update_index') 
#9 [internal function]: search_cron()
#10 /home/xxxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/ultimate_cron/ultimate_cron.module(726): call_user_func('search_cron') 
#11 [internal function]: _ultimate_cron_run_hook('search_cron', Array)
#12 /home/xxxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/background_process/background_process.module(428): call_user_func_array('_ultimate_cron_...', Array)
#13 [internal function]: background_process_service_start('ultimate_cron%3...') 
#14 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/menu.inc(516): call_user_func_array('background_proc...', Array) #15 /home/xxxxx/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() 
#16 {main}
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll tell you how I fixed it.

I got EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node error in my watchlog (recent log messages) after trying to index search (so after cron run). Before my index was let's say 48%, after cron run it stayed same.

I did lots of things, other suggestions didn't help me, but finally I did this and suggest you too:

1. Backup your database!!!
2. Go to phpMyAdmin, to "run sql" section.
3. Put here "SELECT n.nid FROM node n LEFT JOIN search_dataset d ON d.type = 'node' AND d.sid = n.nid WHERE d.sid IS NULL OR d.reindex <> 0 ORDER BY d.reindex ASC, n.nid ASC LIMIT 0,1"
   if you have table prefix, don't forget to put it here.
4. As result you'll get one row with nid, pick it mind.
5. go to node table and run here "SELECT * FROM node WHERE nid=your-nid" where your-nid is nid from step 3
6. Try to open your-website/node/your-nid - for me I got "404 error"
7. Go back to phpMyAdmin and delete this row
8. Run cron again

AS for me I did this 7-8 times to delete all "bad" nodes from database and finally get 100% index

if you don't have access to phpMyAdmin I guess you can do this:

Turn on PHP filter module and backup database
create node type of page for example, to body add code

```
<?php
$result = db_query_range("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n LEFT JOIN {search_dataset} d ON d.type = 'node' AND d.sid = n.nid WHERE d.sid IS NULL OR d.reindex <> 0 ORDER BY d.reindex ASC, n.nid ASC", 0, 1);
echo $result;
?>
```

choose "PHP Filter" of course

Click "Preview"
You should see node id on the screen. Test it like in step 6 of directions for phpMyAdmin and pick in mind
Now you can delete it with adding to the body

```
<?php 
$nid = "your-nid";
db_delete('node')
  ->condition('nid', $nid)
  ->execute();
?>
```

Click Preview again
Run Cron again

Code above I didn't test, so if you'll use it please post here if it works

Thank you and happy indexing ;)

Comment: I tried this and it works great! Cron started to continue and finished search index. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

This error, especially when caused by search (e.g. Apache Solr) is related to the nodes which were indexed, but doesn't exist in Drupal anymore.

This could happen when:

- nodes (also terms or users) has been removed from Drupal, but it's still indexed in Solr,
- multiple instances of Drupal sharing the same Solr, so some nodes were indexed by different instance, but they aren't in the database,

The solution includes:

- clearing the Solr index and cache, then re-index the nodes again,
- if the failing nodes exists - re-saving them would help,
- track down which node is failing to load from your backtrace and try to load it manually (e.g. `drush ev "var_dump(node_load(12));"`) to see why it's failing.

If this happen quiet often, make sure that the removed nodes from Drupal are also removed from Solr index.

For further information, check: [How to debug EntityMalformedException?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/111610/1908) at DA